# How to create intent in DialogFlow which ping user after sometime. like alarm?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I know how to make intents in dialogflow and a little working with webhook.
I need to create an alarm intent which ping user after some time. Is there any solution to follow.

I also saw default alarm intent in dialogflow example, but it does not have any responses so, i didn't understand that intent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/notifications) in DialogFlow to send notifications or alerts to the user based on your logic.

Have a look at this [code sample](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-updates-nodejs) to get started.

Hope this helps!